# Reading the statement "if (x[i][0])."

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to ask a question regarding an IF statement.

Like what is stated from the title, how does the "for" and "If(x[i][0])" works?
The code looks something like this.

```
var dataws1 = source.getRange(1,1,Alast,source.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
var outData = [];
for (var i in dataws1) {
  if (dataws1[i][0] == criteria) { 
    outData.push(dataws1[i])
  }
}
```

From my understanding, the current IF checks the 1st column if it matches with the criteria, then places it inside the array of outData. I tried changing some of the values of the IF to check the other columns but to no avail. I'm still not familiar with Java scripting and I wish to learn more on how to read and on how it works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is copying/pushing every array from `dataws1` which has "criteria" as its first element.

For example:

```js
var dataws1 = [['criteria', 'hello'], ['what', 'is', 'criteria'], ['criteria', 'friend']];
var outData = [];
for (var i in dataws1) {
   if (dataws1[i][0] == 'criteria') { 
      outData.push(dataws1[i]);
   }
}
for (var j in outData) {
  document.write("outData["+j+"] = [" + outData[j] + "]<br>");
}
```

`outData` will contain `outData = [[criteria, hello], [criteria, friend]]`

Comment: I see, That explains a lot. If the "criteria" happens to be on a different order on the array, say [hello, friend, criteria], does it still detect "criteria"? If not, what would be the possible workaround for it?

Comment: I have updated the original answer and added "criteria" to the end of the second array in `dataws1`. As you can see it will not push that array to `outData` since "criteria" is not the first element there. You have many options you can do to include any array with "criteria" somewhere in there. I will mention 3 options: 1) change your `if` statement to `dataws1.includes(criteria)`. 2) change your `if` statement to `dataws1.indexOf(criteria)`. 3) You can also use a loop and go through every element in the array manually and search for "criteria".

Comment: Noted on that. Thank you so much for this Lev.

Answer (score 2):

This loop is taking each item in `dataws1` and then checking the first value in it against "criteria" and if it matches adding it to the `outData` array. So if `dataws1` has 3 items it would be doing something like this:

```
if (dataws1[0][0] == criteria) { 
  outData.push(dataws1[i])
}
if (dataws1[1][0] == criteria) { 
  outData.push(dataws1[i])
}
if (dataws1[2][0] == criteria) { 
  outData.push(dataws1[i])
}
```

```js
var criteria = "match";
var outData = [];
var dataws1 = [
  ['match', 'first'],
  ['nonMatch', 'second'],
  ['match', 'third']
];
for (var i in dataws1) {
  if (dataws1[i][0] == criteria) {
    outData.push(dataws1[i])
  }
}
console.log(outData)
```